# Meteor: Autoform not submitting posts to mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am new to meteor and autoform and am trying to get a form to insert into mongo.  No matter what I have changed it just will not work.  I have no idea what to try next.

I have removed insecure and autopublish.  Attached is a link to my .js and my html file.

I have setup a scheme, gotten the form to show on the html perfectly.  now when I hit submit nothing is being put into mongo.  I have allow rules setup.  I have a ton of console.logs displaying and they all trigger and follow along as if the post was successful.  In fact in the onSuccess I get a document number yet there is nothing in my DB.

Any help here is greatly appreciated. I know it must be something small here but I have racked my brain for hours of endless searching.

.js file without the scheme.  Full js file in the plnkr link

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // ********************************************************
    // ***   Creating the database scheme for the customer account
    // ********************************************************
    customers = new Mongo.Collection("customer");
    AutoForm.debug();
    var postHooks = {
        before: {
            insert: function(doc) {
                console.log("Getting to posting hooks");
                if(Meteor.userId()){
                    doc.createdUser = Meteor.userId();
                    doc.createdDate = Date();
                    console.log("Got to the insert before hook!");
                }
                return doc;
            }
        },
        after: {
            // Replace `formType` with the form `type` attribute to which this hook applies
            insert: function(error, result) {
                console.log("Getting to the after insert function");
                console.log(error);
                console.log(result);
                console.log("New Document ID is " + this.docId);
            }
        },
        onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
            console.log("Getting to the insert sucess area");
            console.log(result);    
        },
        onError: function(formType, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    AutoForm.addHooks('insertCustomer', postHooks);
    Template.customerTemplate.helpers({
        showLoginError: function(){
            return showCustomerSaveError;
        }
    });
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
    customers = new Mongo.Collection("customer");
    customers.allow({
        insert: function (userId, doc) {
            console.log("Getting to the insert server call");
            // the user must be logged in
            return !! userId;
        },
        update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
            // can only change your own documents
            return doc.owner === userId;
        },
        remove: function (userId, doc) {
            // can only remove your own documents
            return doc.owner === userId;
        },
        fetch: ['owner']
    });

}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5pM0Co9luGLIBBNKP5YA

Comment: I haven't read the question, but I suggest you use Autoform.debug(). This will print autoform errors to the console and make it easier to solve your problem.

Comment: I already have that listed in the code and it only prints one thing to the console which is a clean method for the date function. No other statements or messages are produced from the debug.

Comment: Are you certain nothing is in the db? Could it be that you're not publishing the doc and it really is in the db. Showing us your logs might help debug too

Comment: Yes. I put the insecure package back on and ran db find().count and came back 0. Also using Mongol and it is showing 0 records as well

Comment: Autopublish is the package you want

Comment: I want to put it back in? I have removed it.

Comment: You don't want to be using autopublish in general. You want to publish your documents to the client though. Your doc has been added to the db, you're just not seeing it client side because the server hasn't sent it to the client.

Comment: OK I installed auto publish back in and right away mongol could see them, They were posting.  I removed it and then went online to figure out publish and subscribe.  Something none of the tutorials I read on autoform were doing in their code.  Thank you so much for your help.This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the file to the database but not publishing it.
Run `meteor add autopublish` or check in MongoDB itself to see the document.

Comment: This and the comments above helped me to figure out that I was not using the publish and subscribe methods. Thank you for your help.